# How to use variables declared in one program in another program?

Tags: c++

Say I have 2 codes,

**CODE 1**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a=20;
}
```

**CODE 2**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int b=a+20; //where a is declared in code 1
}
```

How to perform this operation? I have searched the internet but there it is showing how to link 2 programs but not a single one has shown how to use variable like this, that I am looking for. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: you need some form of interprocess communication to communicate between seperate processes. C++ doesn't do that out-of the box

Comment: Each process normally is completely separate.  You can connect them by putting your variables in shared memory

Comment: @stark How to put them in a shared memory?

Comment: @idclev463035818 any idea how to do that brother?

Comment: Is this a curiosity question or do you have a specific problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: You could use network socket communications. Or just a data file that is written by 1 application and read by the other. There are many ways to exchange data between applications. Some of them will be OS specific.

Comment: boost has some IPC support here: [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/interprocess.html](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)

Comment: The question as you show it can only be solved by using some shared memory, so what is it you actually want to solve?

Comment: @StephenNewell My computer architecture project requires building an entire real world cache simulator for which there will be some thousands of lines of code ATLEAST. So keeping them all at a single file is really pain in the ass. I thought it will be better to shift them in different files based on their functions. That is why this question. :)

Comment: It will be much easier to make this a single application than to have separate executables + some IPC mechanism. However having a single source file is not necessary or recommended.

Comment: Why easier? Any specific reason?

Comment: There does not seem to be a good reason to have separate processes for this task. You will have extra work to shuffle data between the processes.

Comment: okk..Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

C++ itself does not offer any way to share variables between processes.  But Operating Systems offer that feature.

You can use platform-specific APIs, like [`CreateFileMapping()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga)+[`MapViewOfFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) on Windows (see [Sharing Files and Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/sharing-files-and-memory) on MSDN), [`mmap()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on POSIX, etc, to allocate a block of memory that can be shared between processes, and then you can store data inside that memory as needed.

Or, you can open a line of communication between the two processes, using any number of available inter-process technologies, like pipes, sockets, files, etc.

Comment: any code segment to help with it? or any material to refer?

Comment: Start by reading the documentations I linked to, and do some research.  Plenty of examples posted online for these functions

Comment: As stated above, google for "shared memory" or "interprocess communication" or pipes, COM, DCOM or Corba for more advanced technologies. There is enough material in the web. Wirhout knowing further requirements, it's hard to give advice.